# Given final block not properly padded, encryption issue

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm newbie in cipher, i always get this err

There is a service: http://aesencryption.net/
So i encrypted text in order to put service result in my test cases

```
key: passwd
original: mysecret
bytes: 128 (*don't know what it means but anyway..)
encrypted: EaDf/5rVXY3qMeQx1JmPCw==
```

And i have this scala code

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

import com.github.kondaurovdev.snippets.helper.{CryptoHelper, TryHelper}
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

object Crypter {

  def apply(secret: String): Either[String, Crypter] = {
    for (
      s <- CryptoHelper.getSecretKey(secret).left.map(err => s"Can't get secretKeySpec: $err").right
    ) yield new Crypter(s)
  }

}

class Crypter(secretKey: SecretKeySpec) {

  def encrypt(input: String): Either[String, String] = {

    TryHelper.tryBlock({
      val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)
      val encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"))
      Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted)
    }, "Can't encrypt text")

  }

  //input = base64 encoded string
  def decrypt(input: String): Either[String, String] = {

    for (
      res <- {
        TryHelper.tryBlock({
          val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey)
          val decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(input))
          new String(decrypted)
        }, "Error while decrypting")
      }.right
    ) yield res

  }


}

object CryptoHelper {

  def getSecretKey(myKey: String): Either[String, SecretKeySpec] = {
    TryHelper.tryBlock({
      var key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8")
      val sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
      key = sha.digest(key)
      key = util.Arrays.copyOf(key, 16) // use only first 128 bit
      new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
    }, "Can't build secretKey")
  }

}

object TryHelper {

  def tryBlock[R, E <: Throwable](block: => R, errPrefix: String = "", handle: errorPF = handlePF): Either[String, R] = {
    tryToEither(block).left.map(err => {
      var msg = err.getMessage
      if (errPrefix.nonEmpty) msg = s"$errPrefix: $msg"
      msg
    })
  }

}
```

And i have this test cases:

```
import com.github.kondaurovdev.snippets.Crypter
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class CrypterSpec extends Specification {

  "Crypter" should {

    val crypter = Crypter("passwd")

    "decrypt" in {

      "case 1" in {
        crypter.right.flatMap(_.decrypt("eRKUj0EIXgyqzNFwHWYSLw==")) must beRight("asd")
      }

    }

    "encrypt" in {

      "case 1" in {
        crypter.right.flatMap(_.encrypt("asd")) must beRight("eRKUj0EIXgyqzNFwHWYSLw==")
      }

    }

  }

}
```

But these tests don't pass..

```
> snippets/testOnly snippets.CrypterSpec
[info] CrypterSpec
[info] 
[info] Crypter should
[info]   decrypt
[error]     x case 1
[error]      'Left(Error while decrypting: Given final block not properly padded)' is not Right (CrypterSpec.scala:15)
[info] 
[info]   encrypt
[error]     x case 1
[error]      'Right(bVkPlx7E0OjhCWFyIHzM5Q==)' is Right but 'bVkPlx7E0OjhCWFyIHzM5Q==' is not equal to 'eRKUj0EIXgyqzNFwHWYSLw==' (CrypterSpec.scala:23)
[error] Actual:   bVkPlx7E0OjhCWFyIHzM5Q==
[error] Expected: eRKUj0EIXgyqzNFwHWYSLw==
[info] 
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for specification CrypterSpec
[info] Finished in 6 minutes 3 seconds, 588 ms
[info] 2 examples, 2 failures, 0 error
[info] 
[error] Failed: Total 2, Failed 2, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         snippets.CrypterSpec
[error] (snippets/test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 366 s, completed Jun 3, 2017 11:24:16 PM
```

Comment: I don't know scala, but if this were java then returning `new String(decrypted)` would be a bug. Everything you do on encrypt must be *un*done on decrypt, so you should instead return `new String(decrypted,"UTF-8")`. However, this would not cause a BadPaddingException so I don't yet see what's that.  I might try recreating a java version of your code and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not a scala programmer I converted your code to what I thought was equivalent Java code. My results for encrypting "asd" match yours -- the output was `bVkPlx7E0OjhCWFyIHzM5Q==`. Therefore I conclude that your expectation that the output should be `eRKUj0EIXgyqzNFwHWYSLw==` is what's incorrect.

If you are using the website you referenced for test results, note that they probably are not using the same function to map a string into an AES key as you are. The recommended algorithms to convert low-entropy strings into symmetric keys include pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt, and the like. These are specifically designed for this scenario.

Comment: This error goes away when i changed eRKUj0EIXgyqzNFwHWYSLw on bVkPlx7E0OjhCWFyIHzM5Q, tests are successful. You are right, it's all because of my wrong expectations. I just converted code (from website, look at the bottom of the site) to scala equavalent and thought that it should work. Thank you for help. I want to use encryption in order to encrypt passwords in config files and decrypt them when needed in application